# What is the proper way to split data from Scrapy crawl before output?

Tags: python, scrapy

IF Scrapy goes out and gets me this data:

```
items[{'name': dog, cat, mouse, biff},
      {'name': horse, mule, donkey, gerald},
      {'name': lizard, snake, iguana, horace}]
```

I need to shorten 'name' to only the first item like:

```
items[{'name': dog},{'name': horse},{'name': lizard}]
```

Is this done using loader or pipeline? What is the best way to manipulate data in Scrapy after crawl but before output?

UPDATE:  Thanks for the tips. I was able to solve this problem by combining the suggestions below and this code in a pipeline:

class filterImage(object):

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):

        names = ''
        if item['name']:
            names = item['name'].split(' ')[0]
            item['name'] = names
            return item
        else:
            raise DropItem()
```

Comment: This isn't valid Python - can you update the question?

Comment: Best practise is to create a pipeline and filter your data as you want for scrapy

Comment: It might be just as easy do it when you parse

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I combined Tushar's suggestion with some code from the answer below to get a working solution inside a pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code in a pipeline did the trick:

```
      class filterImage(object):

      def process_item(self, item, spider):
             names = ''
             if item['name']:
                   names = item['name'].split(' ')[0]
                   item['name'] = names
                   return item
              else:
                   raise DropItem()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple piece of string bashing in your parse routine, no need to over complicate things.

```
items = [{'name': 'dog, cat, mouse, biff'},
      {'name': 'horse, mule, donkey, gerald'},
      {'name': 'lizard, snake, iguana, horace'}]

l = []

for item in items:
    l.append({'name': item['name'][0:item['name'].find(',')]})

print l

>>>[{'name': 'dog'}, {'name': 'horse'}, {'name': 'lizard'}]
```

Put that in your `item` and yield it.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I could not get your solution to work inside the item, but I used a bit of your code inside a pipeline to get a working solution.

Comment: Glad it helped. I see you're using `split()`, doesn't that leave a trailing comma on each name?